# I want the app to wakeup every time even if user force quit the iOS app. I'm using background notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, xmppframework

I'm implementing sending the delivery receipts to the opponent user when the app is killed in the XMPP framework. I'm using background notifications to wake up the app when the user kills the app. Once the app is woken up, connect to XMPP and send a delivery receipt to the opponent user. It's working fine when the app is in the background. But it's not working fine when the user kills the app and not using the app for around 5-10 min.

Is there any way to always wake up the app when a background notification arrives?

I added content-available in the notification payload and enabled background modes in capabilities. But still, the app is not woken up when the user forces kill the app. So I want to wake up the app when the user force kills the app.

Comment: When the user force quits the app it will not respond to silent push notifications

Comment: @Paulw11 what will be the solution for it? I want to do like whats app. whats app sends delivery status when a notification receive even if the app kills.